# addClass method not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom, addclass

I am teaching myself jquery. I am trying for the first time to change elements of the dom using jquery. Particularly I am trying to use the method addClass to make a blue rectangle disappear. Here is the simple code:

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test slider</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>


    </head>

    <body>

        <span id="rect"></span>

        <p id="button"> click here </p>

    </body>

</html>
```

css

```
#rect{

    float: left;
    height: 400px;
    width: 550px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.closed {
    height: 0;
}

#button {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-right: 500px;
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#button").click(function(){

        $("#rect").addClass("closed");

    });
});
```

I am expecting the rectangle to disappear when I click the text "click me", but nothing happens. I have checked with an alert box that everything else works.This is my first attempt so I expect it might be something pretty simple I am doing wrong. Any help appreciated.

Comment: css has error #rect is not closed

Comment: Sorry that's a typo in here, i'll fix it.

Comment: Hi Paul if you are not getting any js error in console log. Change .closed to #rect.closed { height: 0; }. When you define styles with an ID vs a Class it takes prescience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the specificity of your CSS selectors. You're trying to override an ID with a class. Which won't work because an ID has a higher level of specificity than a class.

`#` = ID

`.` = Class

The main thing here is to change up the specificity of your selectors and I have outlined a few options below.

#### Change ID to Class

Change `#rect` to `.rect`.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {

  $(".rect").addClass("closed");

});
```

```css
.rect {
  float: left;
  height: 400px;
  width: 550px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.closed {
  height: 0;
}
#button {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-right: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="rect"></span>
<p id="button">click here</p>
```

#### Use a Different CSS Property

If you don't want to change up your ID then you you could have `.closed` apply a property that `#rect` has not set, but would also hide the element like `display: none;`.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {

  $("#rect").addClass("closed");

});
```

```css
#rect {
  float: left;
  height: 400px;
  width: 550px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.closed {
  display: none;
}
#button {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-right: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="rect"></span>
<p id="button">click here</p>
```

#### Increase CSS Selector Specificity

Per the comments below you could change one of your selectors to make it more specific.

Change `.closed` to `#rect.closed` (no space between the `t` and `.`). This will target an element with an ID of `#rect` **and** a class of `.closed`.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {

  $("#rect").addClass("closed");

});
```

```css
#rect {
  float: left;
  height: 400px;
  width: 550px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#rect.closed {
  height: 0;
}
#button {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-right: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="rect"></span>
<p id="button">click here</p>
```

Comment: Or change the stylesheet to `#rect.closed` (without whitespace!!)

Comment: Yes, you could also do that among a number of things. Kinda flew right past that one, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using an ID for your span and a class to add the class refuses to overwrite the ID's height. One way to correct this is using `!important` which demands it to overwrite anything else determining the height for that element. Another way would be to have two classes that you toggle

Toggle Method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#button").click(function(){

        $("#rect").toggleClass("closed open");

    });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6w25dfa0/)

Important Method:

```
.closed {
    height: 0!important;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/h9e5ngha/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to make the rectangle invisible you could try setting the display property to none:

```
#rect{

    float: left;
    height: 400px;
    width: 550px;
    background-color: blue;

.closed {
    display: none; 
}

#button {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-right: 500px;
}
```